# Would the ability to eat and digest food help to fuel the stigma against sentient androids?

Tags: science-fiction, robots, far-future

If androids were able to eat they would beat humans in one more jealous way because along with immortality and a tougher and stronger but at the same time having a soft body they could also eat as much as they want without needing to worry about health issues. Diseases caused by overeating like high cholesterol, severe obesity, high blood pressure and even cancer would not exist on androids but the robots would sinply digest the food without gaining any nutrient from it or could eat food as an extra energy source.

In Detroit Become Human there is an agressive behavior towards androids because they caused massive unemployment rate among humans but I was wondering that if they could eat any food and drink this would be an extra reason for humans to stigmatize them.

Also there could be another indirect unwanted effect: The food price could increase a lot because of a "superflous" (unlike humans robots can live without food having other energy sources and humans eat to live not only for pleasure obviously) increased demand making humans even more mad toward sentient robots.

But in real life we do not get jealous of motorcycles because they can run in speeds impossible for people and we do not get jealous of computers because they solve in fraction of seconds math problems that even a college student would take hours to solve.

Comment: Apart for the internal contradictions (digest the food without gaining any nutrient from it, for example) you have already answered your question:  food price could increase a lot because of increased demand

Comment: People have been jealous of machine tools in the past, because they could do work faster than humans lacking the same tools. Consider the [luddites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luddite).

Comment: But why would they eat? Eating more and faster isn't _better_ for the economy, its worse

Answer (score 1):

**Certainly! Why would they eat?**

Humans will regard the androids as wannabe people, pretending to eat while they are not, only to keep up appearances as fake humans. They will regard it as a waste of food and they will frame the androids as profiting from humans ("they took our jobs, now even take our food") and it will help folks who advocate androids will be future replacements for humans. Androids don't need food, so for them it is luxury. Many humans feel androids don't deserve luxury, because they are not supposed to enjoy anything.